# Python console doesn't get updated (with PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new at Python, and I am using PyCharm. I have trying to use the console to interactively check what my functions do, but once the functions have been loaded, they don't get updated. More precisely :

Given a set of functions in "functions.py", I write in the the console "from functions import *"
This works at first, but when the functions in "functions.py" are changed, the console doesn't see it, even if I relauch the "import" command.

Any idea of what I shoud do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your module by doing `reload(functions)`.

Then do the `from functions import *` one more time (as you're importing everything).

Then it will work.

Alternatively, if you're importing just the module:

```
import functions
```

and calling it from the module namespace:

```
functions.my_function()
```

then only `reload(functions)` is sufficient (no need to call `import` again).

I've tested all of that on Python 2.7.6 in an interpreter session.

Comment: Thanks! On python 3.4, you need to first import the reload functions from "importlib".

Comment: Right, this will probably be a useful clarification for people having similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
reload(functions)
```

And then:

from functions import myfunc

Thanks to Nobilis for the correction.

Comment: `reload` won't work on a function, it explicitly asks for a `module` type